# How to find the specific word in kendo UI grid in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have Kendo UI Grid in MVC4 Project. After data binding, i want to check the each and every cells, whether it contains specific words like "AA" or "BB". If words found, need to change the color of that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery and build a selector as:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
// Color cell containing AA
grid.tbody
    .find(":contains('AA')")
    .closest("td")
    .css("background", "red");

// Color rows containing BB
grid.tbody
    .find(":contains('BB')")
    .closest("tr")
    .css("background", "red");
```

See it action here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/Abv97/1/